# Wordpress and multisites, the rigth choice?

Tags: multisite, permissions, single-sign-on

I'm about to start a website, for a non-profit organization, and I need it to be a multi-site platform. I do not know Worpress but I know there is a multi-site option. Thus I'm wondering if Wordpress is the right solution ...

So here what I need to support :

**[1 platform, 1 community]**

- a single user base, and SSO (1 login to every sites)

**[several sites, several looks]**

- each site needs to have his own style (colors, font, images... basically only css imo)

**[an accurate permission system]**

- each site needs to have his own administrators (could be 1, or 2 admin per site). Each admin could only manage is own site and should be considered as, more or less, a regular user in others sites.
- each site should has his own usergroups, and admins of the site should be able to manage usergroups and add / remove users. Usergroups need to have permission to view / comment / post content.

I'm aware it might not fit all my needs, but I just wondering how difficult is it to achieve that using Worpress : do I need to add tons of modifications or plugins ? Is WP not the best choice to achieve that ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I suggest that you start by looking at Roles and Capabilities: http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities and then add a user role management plugin. This should solve the permissions bit.

Comment: @ChristineCooper Thanks a lot, your link helps. I've read [this article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) too.
WP seems to be a great tool for me. I can't accept your answer since it's a comment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, yes, Wordpress could work. Wordpress permission system is built on [roles and capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities). To manage your permissions, you can use a plugin such as the [User Role Editor](http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/).

Comment: Not a problem. Almost everything that you need can be found in the codex pages. Also, please use the search here, there are some stellar questions and answers.